# How to display same records all together having same product id in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database

```
id    product_id    size

1     185       3
2     195       4
3     185       4
4     198       1
```

I want to display the of size records together having the same product id if more than one record. If it's only one product id display size as it is.

I have tried this:

```
$qq = mysql_query("select product_id,GROUP_CONCAT(size SEPRATOR ',')AS
size from sizes group by product_id");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($qq))  {
   $ad = $row['size'];
}
```

I am getting this error:

```
error:mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, 
boolean given in /home/clebster/public_html/fun.php
```

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-handling.html

Comment: $qq=mysql_query("select product_id,GROUP_CONCAT(size SEPRATOR ',')AS size from sizes group by product_id");  
                
                     while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($qq)) { 
                     $ad=$row['size'];
                     }

Comment: Am getting this error:mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/clebster/public_html/fun.php

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
select product_id , group_concat (`Size` separator ',') as `Size` from tablename group by product_id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql="SELECT size FROM tbl WHERE id='$product_id'";
$res=mysql_query($sql);
$num_rows=myqli_num_rows($res);
if($num_rows>0)
{
for($i=0; $i<$num_rows;$i++)
{
$data=mysqli_fetch_array($res);
echo $data['size'];
}


}
```

**Try this.**

Comment: Thank you Rohan Kumar Shrestha.I tried this.its works. but how can i add comma in between this?Can you please answer me..

Comment: You should add comma in between the data you printed best option is to put the value in table

Comment: without refreshing the page can be updated but you should use ajax for that

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `group_concat` along with `group by` clause as

```
Select product_id, group_concat(size) as size
from product_table group by product_id
order by id asc
```

Comment: First of all thank you Uchiha .I tried this getting the answer only after refreshing page the page.why it is so..please answer me.

Comment: No errors.insert it nothing displayed until refresh it.

Comment: Can you post your within your question what you were doing over here